# PHP - locale specific date format for English and French

Tags: php, locale, strftime

Locale specific dates present an interesting problem, not only do we need to specify the appropriate translation (Ex: `September`=>`septembre`) but we also need to ensure the format is in the right order (Ex: `September 15, 2018`=>`15 septembre 2018`)

PHP's date function `date()` is English only, so that can be immediately disregared.

Instead, my "research" has pointed me to [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php). I prepared the following code: `echo strftime('%b %e, %Y',strtotime($date));`

This outputs: `May 1, 2018` and `mai 1, 2018`. This seemed to solve the issue, that is until we had our bilingual testers identify that the days should be formatted 1 mai 2018.

What is the best way of dealing with this, is it a static class? I want to prepare our solution following best practices, but I have not found the answer.

```
class LocaleDate
{
    public static function date($date)
    {
        $locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
        if ($locale == "fr_CA" || $locale == "fr_CA.UTF-8") {
            return strftime('%e %b %Y',strtotime($date));
        } else {
            return strftime('%b %e, %Y',strtotime($date));
        }
    }
}

echo LocaleDate::date($date)
```

Would that be the best way to go about this issue? Needing to identifty the locale and outputting from there? Seems tedious if you have multiple languages to deal with.

Comment: [`setlocale`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Andrew It does, but that isn't really what I am asking. setlocale doesn't specify date formats, unless I have completely overlooked it's functionality?

Comment: Oh I see. No, you can't set the format unfortunately(which is sort of silly). The only relevant information I could find was using `str_replace` and other hack-ish solutions. So all things considered, you're on the right path.

Comment: use the DateTime and DateTimeZone classes

Comment: @delboy1978uk DateTime is English specific and DateTimeZone is unrelated to the question

Comment: Not if you use `IntlDateFormatter`

Answer (score 0):

Use the DateTime class alongside the IntlDateFormatter.

Example:

```
<?php

$dt = new DateTime;

$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('fr_FR', IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
$formatter->setPattern('E d.M.yyyy');

echo $formatter->format($dt);
```

Output:

```
jeu. 17.5.2018
```

Have a play with it here: https://3v4l.org/tuEM0

Check the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php